# ReferenceError {wildcard} is not defined firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a cloud function "createUser" that will trigger everytime a new user is written in firestore. Data is written successfully and cloud function is triggered also. But it gives me an error that "userId" wildcard is not defined. I included esLint in my project but I don't think it's related.

Here is index.js code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    // Get an object representing the document
     // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
     const newValue = snap.data();

     // access a particular field as you would any JS property
     const name = newValue.name;

    // perform desired operations ...
});
```

Firestore structure

```
users
    vWil2QSrY0YBQH346pYlemQasdf
        email:
        name:
```

Log

```
ReferenceError: userId is not defined
at exports.createUser.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/user_code/index.js:8:34)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:827:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more specific about exactly what the error message is, and what you're doing that causes it to be shown?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the error.

Comment: And what you are doing to cause that error to be shown?

Comment: @DougStevenson creating new user or document.

Comment: So that message appears in the Functions console when triggered?  I don't see what could possibly be causing that.